# Proving $X\setminus\bigcap_{i\in\Lambda}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}(X\setminus A_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a universe. Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in \Lambda}$ be a family of sets in $X$, where $\Lambda$ is a set of index. Could you help me to prove?

$$X\setminus\bigcap_{i\in\Lambda}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}(X\setminus A_i)$$

where $X\,\backslash A_i$ denotes the complement of $A_i$

Answer (score 2):

Let $L,R$ be the left and right hand side sets.

$x \in L$ **iff** $x \notin \cap_i A_i$ **iff** there exists $i$ such that $x \notin A_i$ **iff** there exists $i$ such that  $x \in X \setminus A_i$
**iff** $ x \in \cup_i (X \setminus A_i)$ **iff** $x \in R$.